# Issue with Firebase Cloud Messaging Service Worker and self.addEventListener

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've successfully built an FCM notification service worker for my web app, and it's working OK so far. I used toastr to present notifications within the web app. I'm currently having an issue with the service worker when the web site is not open. Here is my code from firebae-messaging-sw.js:

```
//Firebase initialized above here
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
const notiTitle = payload.data.title;
var body = payload.data.body;

const opts = {
    icon : "/ui/img/icons/android-chrome-256x256.png",
    actions : [
        {
            action: 'view-ticket',
            title: 'View Ticket',
            icon: null
        }
    ],
    body: body
    //url: link
};
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    const clickedNotification = event.notification;
    clickedNotification.close();

    if(!event.action) {
        return;
    }

    switch(event.action) {
        case 'view-ticket':
            var promiseChain = clients.openWindow(payload.data.link);
            break;
    }

    event.waitUntil(promiseChain);

});
return self.registration.showNotification(notiTitle, opts);

});
```

It's *almost* working perfectly except for one issue. When I send my first test notification, `payload.data.link` is parsed ok. But on the next notification, `payload.data.link` is not updated, so the wrong link is sent. I *think* that maybe `self.addEventListener` is in the wrong place, but I'm not sure how else to put it (I obviously can't do it after the `return`).

Any idea where I should put the event listener code?

Comment: I did verify that my payload is delivering different URLs properly:

{
    "to": "recip_fcm_tok",
    "data": {
        "link": "https://my.app.com/MyApp/Service/TicketDetail/17749",
        "body": "Ticket Regarding: \"Test Ticket Summary\" updated.",
        "title": "Ticket Number 17749 updated"
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it! I was able to repair this by adding a variable and moving `addEventListener` outside of `setBackgroundMessageHandler` like so:

```
//Firebase started up above
var clickDestination; //init this variable

//add event listener before background message handler and use clickDestination
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
const clickedNotification = event.notification;
clickedNotification.close();
if (!event.action) {
    return;
}

if(event.action === 'view-ticket') {
    var promise = new Promise(function () {
        return clients.openWindow(clickDestination);
    });
    event.waitUntil(promise);
}


});


messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
const notiTitle = payload.data.title;
var body = payload.data.body;
clickDestination = payload.data.link; //set clickDestination based on payload
/*self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    event.notification.close();
    event.waitUntil(self.clients.openWindow(payload.data.link));
});*/

const opts = {
    icon : "/ui/img/icons/android-chrome-256x256.png",
    actions : [
        {
            action: 'view-ticket',
            title: 'View Ticket',
            icon: '/ui/img/icons/ticket-icon.png'
        }
    ],
    body: body
};


return self.registration.showNotification(notiTitle, opts);
```